# When I update react-dev-utils to the @next version. I can't find typescriptFormatter and WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin

Tags: webpack, create-react-app

when updating webpack from 4 to 5, I got the error:

```
TypeError: message.split is not a function
```

which is thrown in `react-dev-utils/formatWebpackMessages.js`.

Then I update `react-dev-utils` to then `@next` version which fix this.

However in the `@next` version, there are no `WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin` and `typescriptFormatter` in `react-dev-utils`, and they are used in my `webpack.config.js` file which is working with `webpack4`.

How can I fix this or do I need these two utils in my typescript project?

Can anyone give me a template of `webpack.config.js` for a typescript project using webpack5?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I had this issue too.

They endedup removing `WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin` for Webpack 5 so you have to remove its usage too. It will be a similar change to this PR:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/11170/files

Similarly, `typescriptFormatter` was removed in this change:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/10004
For this one you'll need to make the same changes to the `webpack.config.js` file.

Comment: could you please provide clarification on whether this property has been entirely removed or if it has been replaced by another key? I have been seeking official documentation or a pull request (PR) related to this matter, but regrettably, I have not found any.