# Error: Cannot find module 'react-dev-utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, node-modules

I have React.js application with the connection of Rust. Problem is about running the application. When I try to run npm start it return this error:

```
  throw err;
  ^
Error: Cannot find module 'react-dev-utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin'
Require stack:
- /Users/elchinfarhad/Desktop/IndoorNavigation/react-client/config/webpack.config.js
- /Users/elchinfarhad/Desktop/IndoorNavigation/react-client/scripts/start.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/elchinfarhad/Desktop/IndoorNavigation/react-client/config/webpack.config.js:19:39)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1099:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/elchinfarhad/Desktop/IndoorNavigation/react-client/config/webpack.config.js',
    '/Users/elchinfarhad/Desktop/IndoorNavigation/react-client/scripts/start.js'
  ]
}
```

Point is it was working before and I did not change anything, but later when I try npm start it return the above error. I try to delete node_modules and package-lock.json and install again but nothing changes. Can someone please help how can I solve this problem.

Comment: It's been answered here: [Stack Overflow 68827938](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68827938/when-i-update-react-dev-utils-to-the-next-version-i-cant-find-typescriptforma)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. It is probably about your npm version. I downgraded my npm version to 6.14.11, and the problem was solved.

```
npm install -g npm@6.14.11
```