# can you help? Error: Cannot find module 'react-dev-utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules, npm-start

```
Error: Cannot find module 'react-dev-utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\stromboli\IdeaProjects\projects-ui\config\webpack.config.js
- C:\Users\stromboli\IdeaProjects\projects-ui\scripts\start.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1014:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:884:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1074:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\stromboli\IdeaProjects\projects-ui\config\webpack.config.js:18:39)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1185:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1205:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1034:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:923:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1074:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\stromboli\IdeaProjects\projects-ui\scripts\start.js:32:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1185:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1205:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1034:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:923:14) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\stromboli\\IdeaProjects\\projects-ui\\config\\webpack.config.js',
    'C:\\Users\\stromboli\\IdeaProjects\\projects-ui\\scripts\\start.js'
  ]
}
```

No matter what I do localhost won't open and I get this error. The github solutions shown didn't work either, how can I fix it I'm about to go crazy.

npm ls react-dev-utils
`-- react-dev-utils@12.0.1

Comment: I think this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68827938/when-i-update-react-dev-utils-to-the-next-version-i-cant-find-typescriptforma

Comment: @mc.user could you please provide clarification on whether this property has been entirely removed or if it has been replaced by another key? I have been seeking official documentation or a pull request (PR) related to this matter, but regrettably, I have not found any.

Answer (score 2):

In your config find `webpack.config.dev.js` and remove the following:

```
const WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin');
 
module.exports = {
    // ...
    plugins: [
        // If you require a missing module and then `npm install` it, you still have
        // to restart the development server for Webpack to discover it. This plugin
        // makes the discovery automatic so you don't have to restart.
        // See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/186
        new WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin(paths.appNodeModules),
    ]
}
```

Comment: @tdy  could you guys please provide clarification on whether this property has been entirely removed or if it has been replaced by another key? I have been seeking official documentation or a pull request (PR) related to this matter, but regrettably, I have not found any.

Comment: @ShivamVerma All I did on this post was some minor edits for formatting. Thee Alchemist is the one who posted the answer and might know more.